# Return of iw wlan0 scan freq <freq>

Tags: embedded-linux, wifi, android-wireless, adbwireless

I am using iw to get all APs nearby. The loop is run for 10 times. The order of MACs remains same across all loops.

But when I run the scan on different system simultaneously, the order of MACs are not same to that of the other.

Whats the logic of this order of MAC?

I feel power and frequency bands has a role but trend is not fully confirming.

Comment: Since this is a programming site: why don't you sort the output on MAC if you require a particular order.

Comment: Actually I observe that the order has some dependence on proximity to APs.                I want to keep the sequence as it is observed. If I get logic of order for a scan I can plan accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps that during a scan, those AP's are found first because they are in closer proximity, and the order of the list is based on the order in which the AP's respond to a scan?

Comment: Yes that the logic but to surprise 
1. if same script is ran on two machines, simultaneously orders are not same on both.

Comment: Interference, slightly different antenna angles, crosstalk/reflections, who knows. Also, if an AP doesn't support multiple streams it could very well be that a client has to wait for another client to finish talking to an AP before it can proceed (although I'm not sure how WiFi scans work, so that might not be an issue).